# Tasks are not being executed, Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an Ansible playbook to configure servers for the minimum configuration that we need. Here is part of the script I have:

```
---
- 
  name: Install Git, OpenJDK, MySql, Docker, Bamboo
  hosts: myservers
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    bamboo: atlassian-bamboo
    bamboover: 5.12.2.1
    dlpath: software/bamboo/downloads/binary
    tmp: /var/tmp
    installto: opt
    datahome: /srv/bamboo-data
    svcuser: someuser
    dbuser: someotheruser
    dbpass: somepassword
  tasks:
    - name: install epel-release
      yum: pkg=epel-release state=latest
    - name: install the open-vm-tools, htop, mlocate, ansible, autoconf, wget, java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64, Development tools
      yum: state=present name={{item}}
      with_items:
        - open-vm-tools
        - htop
        - mlocate
        - ansible
        - autoconf
        - wget
        - java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64
        - "Development tools"
    ## The task gets here and it doesn't continue for some reason.
    - name: Reboot the server after install
      command: reboot 
    - name: wait for server to come back
      local_action: 
        module: wait_for 
          host={{inventory_hostname}}
          port=22
          state=started 
          delay=1 
          timeout=300
      sudo: false
    - name: updatedb
      command: updatedb >> playbook.log.txt
    - name: install mysql, mysql-community-server
      yum: name={{item}} state=present 
      with_items:
        - http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
        - mysql-community-server
    - name: Start of mysqld
      command: service mysqld start >> playbook.log.txt
     [...] #Continues...
```

I don't understand what is wrong. During my investigation I found that there was a known issue with ansible when a host can't be reached (That's what happens in my case). Relevant issue: [ISSUE](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14665) The issue is resolved though and this is my version of Ansible:

[image]

I tried deleting all hosts from my ansible hosts file and leaving only one that I CAN access. To no avail, it just isn't executing all tasks.

This is the output of the playbook:

[image]

Could someone maybe suggest a different approach or better yet a solution?

Comment: I believe you need to prefix your `yum` package group "Development Tools" with an `@`.  [Ansible `yum` module examples.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html#examples).  Also documented in the [`yum` module notes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html#notes).

Comment: @thankyour Yes that was the main issue, thanks!!! Feel free to answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Glad it was a simple fix! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package groups must be prefixed with an `@`. From the Ansible [yum module notes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html#notes):

> Package groups are specified as “@development-tools” and environment groups are “@^gnome-desktop-environment”.